# Sales orders not showing for new Admin user in magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, user-roles, admin-user

I have created new User here

**System -> Permission**

Assigned User Role as Administrator

But when logged in with the new user which i created now, I can't see the orders for the newly created admin user.

Under **Sales -> Orders**

Did re-index and cache flush.

What is the problem here? Can anyone look into this and update me, please.

Some of the links referred and suggested to disable Asynchronus reindex,

Disable Asynchronous indexing under Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings

That also didn't solve for me.

My Magento version is 2.2.6.

I am getting one console error like below.

```
  data-storage.js:270 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null
at UiClass.onRequestComplete
```

Comment: set role resources to 'all'

Comment: @magefms, yes its there already

Comment: @magefms, could you check this issue, i can't see any grids for the new admin user

Comment: @magefms, if set to yes, that user also will become admin user, that we don't want make as admin user

Comment: Refer link- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269811/magento-2-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-items-of-null-for-restrict

Comment: @Dharmendrakothe, that link has no answer, he is also facing same issue..

Comment: are you using any any third party plugins for sales order?

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal,Exactly for sales order i am not using, to print invoice pdf i used one module, other than that i used click n collect module, not any other modules

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with new users, doesn't matter if they are super admins or restricted users. They can't see all orders.

Did you find a solution? filtering, reindex, cache... nothing works.

Comment: For me one extension making problem, after disabling it worked for me