# Magento 2: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null for restricted permission user

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, error, magento2.2.7, console

**Note: This is not a duplicate of any similar error**

I have found a strange bug in Magento 2. It shows the following error in the browser's console for only restricted admin user (the user which has not full rights of the admin panel).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null
    at UiClass.onRequestComplete (data-storage.js:270)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
    at done (jquery.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)
```

[image: Console Error]

To replicate the issue, follow the process below:

- Login to the backend with a user with full backend permission.
- Create a new user role from **System** >> **User Roles** with **Custom** Resource Access. For example, select only the **Dashboard** from the resources list. (You can choose any other)

[image: Create role]

- After creating the role, create a new admin user with the role which you created in the previous step.
- Login to the backend with new user's login credentials in another browser or after logging out the current user.
- Open the browser's console and check the error mentioned above.

**Note: I have noticed the same error from Magento versions 2.2.4 to 2.2.7.**

Comment: hi @Mohit, did you get the solution for this issue? I am also facing the same

Comment: No @jafar-pinjar, not yet.

Comment: hi @Mohit, any temporary fix u did? or any suggestions to avoid this

Comment: have you installed any custom modules related to orders?

Comment: No, actually my question is not related to orders. I am having this error on every page in the backend for any restricted user.

Comment: yes, for me also, is the order grid showing for you? in my case its not loading the grid, for u only console error showing? or grid also not showing

Comment: For me, the sales order grid is loading fine. Please check https://nimb.ws/ldIqo6 for reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93329/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Answer (score 0):

after adding resource 'Basic Configuration Section' under 'Stores->Settings->Configuration', My local loaded fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @jonas-chen for sharing the solution.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be issue for new Magento version but M2.x and M3.X has issue: change data source format to below:

```xml
<dataSource name="listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```