# Magento 2.2.4 ,how to show 3 products per row insteadd of 4 on category list page?

Tags: product-list, magento2.2.4

Magento 2 , how to show **3 products per row** instead of **4** on **category list** page?

Comment: Kindly Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find below css styles in [Magento Blank Theme directory]/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less line 290 - 295

```
.products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-products .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-products.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
.page-products.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
```

**NOTE :** Do not edit core file,Copy this file into your custom theme and then make changes into that .

Comment: thank You FOr your Help! But CSS Code Is not working.

Comment: after make above changes, you need run all commands again and then check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, have you faced this issue, can you help me on this please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269811/magento-2-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-items-of-null-for-restrict