# Magento 2 - Pixel code on specific products

Tags: magento2

I have a pixel tracking code and I want to add this code to some products

If I add this in

> Content -> Design -> Configuratoin

But it will appear on all pages, I want to add it in some specific products. How can I do this?

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have different pixel codes for different products? Or same pixel code for specific products?

Comment: example: 1 pixel code for 10 products, another pixel code for 30 more products and so on...

Comment: You can create attribute name pixel code for products and call one phtml in header and add add the pixel code. Let me add an answer. Can you add the sample pixel code to your question?

Comment: Good idea, I think doing this one on attribute level would be easy. Yes please add this one in answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one module with name **STech_Pixel** by following steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/Pixel/registration.php

with below code:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Pixel',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Pixel/etc/module.xml

with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Pixel" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **InstallSchema.php** under

> app/code/STech/Pixel/Setup/InstallSchema.php

with below code:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Pixel\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'pixel_code',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Pixel Code',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Step 4:**
Create **catalog_product_view.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Pixel/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="pixel" template="STech_Pixel::pixel.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

**Step 5:**
Create **pixel.phtml** under

> app/code/STech/Pixel/view/frontend/templates/pixel.phtml

with below code:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($pixel_code = $_product->getPixelCode()): ?>
    <?php // Add your javascript code here and replace the pixel code with php variable $pixel_code ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy if needed.

Comment: hi @Sukumar, can you check the below issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266115/sales-orders-not-showing-for-new-admin-user-in-magento2

Comment: It is similar to this issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269811/magento-2-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-items-of-null-for-restrict

Comment: Great Sukumar Gorai. Very detailed answer. many thanks :)

Comment: Welcome Happy coding.